# instagram Invalid header: X-Insta-Forwarded-For is required for this operation

Tags: instagram

I have a problem when I try to give a picture admired by instagram api

Error message that appears to me

```
stdClass Object ( [code] => 403 [error_type] => OAuthForbiddenException [error_message] => Invalid header: X-Insta-Forwarded-For is required for this operation )
```

Code which is used to give the image impress

```
print_r($instagram->likeMedia(783976945516349891_353981601));
```

can you help me :(

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you have to do is turn off the Enforce signed header option on your Instagram API developer account.

1. Go to http://instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/ (you may have to log in)
2. Click the Edit button to the right of your application name
3. Scroll down to the bottom of the page and unclick the 'Enforce signed header' checkbox
4. Click Update Client

That should get rid of your error.

Comment: For me my app was running smoothly till i get this error , i turned off the Enforce signed header , but didn't work .

since the main question is not marked as answered yet , i don't know if @abdullah fixed his issue yet with your solution .

Comment: did you guys find a solution for this error ? i have same issue